# Qt Set background Color of QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I am very new to Qt and I am making some changes to a program. What I am trying to do is get a QPushButton called `start_` to change its color when clicked. The button is declared here:

```
void StatusTab::CreateControlFrame() {
start_ = new QPushButton(tr("Start Capture"), this);
start_->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
button_layout->addWidget(start_, 0, 0, 1, 1);
connect(start_, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnStartClicked()));
}
```

I am guessing that the code needs to be added in the `OnStartClicked()` method but I am not sure what functions I need to use. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Qt Designer, with which you can add widgets and adjust their apparence.conveniently. Qt provides QSS to Customize widgets. [Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html).In this case, you can use

```
start_->setStyleSheet("QPushButton:pressed { \
    background-color: rgb(224, 0, 0);        \
    border-style: inset;                     \
}");
```

You can set QSS in Qt Designer.